# Converting an app to a Binary

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have been given a project and asked to convert it to binary so my boss can submit it to the App Store. I am using xcode 4.3.1; how can I do this?

Sorry: I don't have any code (I don't think this can be done through code) or any thing that i have done to demonstrate.

Comment: The link you gave me directs to the dev site of apple. What do you want me to look at ?

Comment: Is it just to open the project and Build it and then archive the file ?

Comment: Login here https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action and go to the iOS provisioning portal and follow the distribution instructions from there. Otherwise start with some of the beginner tutorials.

Comment: Do you have a developer account? Are you able to test your app on the simulator? on a device? Do you have access to iTunes connect? Was the app added to iTunes connect?

Comment: Yes, i have a developer account, and i do know to compile and run the app on both stimulator and device. I only need to know how to `convert iphone code to Binary`

Comment: @Illep converting it to binary does not make sense as that is exactly what the compiler does for you already when building debug-versions of your App. What you actually want to do is building a version of your app that is signed using the app-store-distribution certificate. As noted by others, Apple does provide a huge, well written pile of information on that issue. Check the Apple documentation on the keyword DISTRIBUTION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already been testing on an iOS device, then you already have a binary.  It's what gets downloaded to the device to run your app.

What you might actually need to do is to learn how to archive, codesign, and submit the app.

For that, nothing beats reading Apple's documentation.  All of it.  Not some short hint or a paragraph or two.  Lots can go wrong if you don't read it all.

Answer (score 1):

Open Xcode.  Click Help.  Type "Distributing Applications" in the search.

The developer website also has mountains of information on how to do this.